# How to left align the contents of a colored cell in table?

Tags: tables

In the following table I want to left align three cells containing: cell1, cell1000 and cell100,000 only. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{multirow}
\title{Question}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is the content of this document.
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption {Mixture samples Set 1} \label{mixset1}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
{\bf{Mixture}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\bf{Total (pg)}} &  {\bf{Minor Contributor}} \\
{\bf{Ratios}} &{} &{\bf{DNA (pg)}} \\
\cellcolor{Gray}{4:3:2:1} & \cellcolor{Gray}{cell1} & \cellcolor{Gray}{100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25}  \\
 {10:5:2:1} & {cell1000} & 
{100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25}  \\
\cellcolor{Gray}{10:5:1} & \cellcolor{Gray}{cell100,000} & \cellcolor{Gray}{100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To left-align one cell only, you can use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{<cell contents>}`. Also, since you have complete rows with gray background, you can save typing by issuing one `\rowcolor{Gray}` command before the respective rows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{multirow}
\title{Question}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is the content of this document.
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Mixture samples Set 1} \label{mixset1}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \textbf{Mixture} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Total (pg)}} & \textbf{Minor Contributor} \\
    \textbf{Ratios}  & {}                                   & \textbf{DNA (pg)}          \\ \rowcolor{Gray}
    4:3:2:1          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{cell1}            & 100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25    \\
    10:5:2:1         & \multicolumn{1}{l}{cell1000}         & 100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25    \\ \rowcolor{Gray}
    10:5:1           & \multicolumn{1}{l}{cell100,000}      & 100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25    \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks:

- use of the `\bf` is depreciated for + 20 years
- content of cells not need to be enclose by curly braces
- for coloring of rows exist macro/command `\rowcolor`
- with use of `makecell` first two rows can be merged into one

MWE (for table only):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \caption {Mixture samples Set 1} \label{mixset1}
\begin{tabular}{clc}
\thead{Mixture\\Ratios} 
            &   \thead{Total (pg)} 
                            &  \thead{Minor\\ Contributor} \\
\rowcolor{Gray}
 4:3:2:1    &   cell1       &   100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25     \\
10:5:2:1    &   cell1000    &   100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25     \\
\rowcolor{Gray}
10:5:1      &   cell100,000 &   100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25     \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just change the specifier for the cells to `{clc}` and your rows will be aligned center-left-center. More information on how to specify column-alignment is found here: [Latex Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment).

This will also left-align the headline of your table, but it's barely visible in your example and would look weird anyway if the headline is aligned differently than the cells

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{multirow}
\title{Question}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This is the content of this document.
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption {Mixture samples Set 1} \label{mixset1}
\begin{tabular}{clc} % <==== here's the important change
{\bf{Mixture}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\bf{Total (pg)}} &  {\bf{Minor Contributor}} \\
{\bf{Ratios}} &{} &{\bf{DNA (pg)}} \\
\cellcolor{Gray}{4:3:2:1} & \cellcolor{Gray}{cell1} & \cellcolor{Gray}{100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25}  \\
 {10:5:2:1} & {cell1000} & 
{100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25}  \\
\cellcolor{Gray}{10:5:1} & \cellcolor{Gray}{cell100,000} & \cellcolor{Gray}{100, 50, 25, 12.5, 6.25}  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```